# Raw mouse input X11

Tags: linux, mouse, x11

I need the raw mouse deltas for an X11 application. Is there a way to do this without having to open a link directly to the device driver? The warping mouse trick won't work in this particular application. Also, Qt, SDL, etc. is not an option. XInput2 is OK.